# "Error: Syntax Error unexpected token" in custom Angular Directive attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm testing out angular & trying to build a custom angular directive, but I'm running into weird console errors.

My directive is defined as:

```
.directive('ipRecentActivityItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      'title': '@title',
      'icon': '@icon',
      'timeago': '@timeago',
      'meta': '@meta',
    },
    templateUrl: IP_PATH + '/app/components/recent-activity/recent-activity-item.tpl.html'
  }
});
```

My template is:

```
<div class="recent-activity-item">
  <div class="recent-activity-content">
    <div class="recent-activity-message">
      <a href="" class="recent-activity-title">
        {{title}}
      </a>
      <div class="recent-activity-meta">
        {{meta}}
      </div>
      <div data-ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="recent-activity-timeago">{{timeago}}</a>
</div>
```

Then, in my view, I'm trying to call it with:

```
<div data-ip-recent-activity-item 
  title="My Item Title" 
  icon="My item icon" 
  timeago="4 hours ago" 
  meta="someone commented on an issue in garageband">
  My Item content
</div>
```

In the rendered page, everything is showing as it should, but the console is throwing these types of errors: `Error: Syntax Error: Token 'Item' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the expression [My Item Title] starting at [Item Title].`

If I get rid of the spaces, the error goes away, but I don't understand why that is. Can anyone enlighten me? Thanks! I'm still new to the angular arena, be kind! :)

EDIT: Forgot to mention I'm running angular version 1.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I think this was related to angular caching the template aggressively.

I had tried playing around adding an `ng-show` on the elements by passing in the attributes ( {{title}}, etc..). This borked somethings, so I removed it. I think angular was still using the cached version when looking up the template which threw the errors, but it was still able to render properly. The above code works just fine! Trixy!

For reference, I'm using the following template now:

```
<div class="recent-activity-item">
  <div class="recent-activity-content">
    <div class="recent-activity-message">
      <a href="" class="recent-activity-title" data-ng-hide="title === ''">
        {{title}}
      </a>
      <div class="recent-activity-meta" data-ng-hide="meta === ''">
        {{meta}}
      </div>
      <div data-ng-transclude></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="" class="recent-activity-timeago" data-ng-hide="timeago === ''">{{timeago}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: The edit should actually be in this answer, not in the original post.

Comment: You should accept the answer that fixed the issue (Jason More's), not edit your question with the answer

Comment: I've moved the answer you posted out of the question, and edited it into here for you. Please be sure to do it that way in the future.

Comment: If anyone else runs into this `syntax-error-unexpected-token` it can be as simple as a syntax error- spelling wrong or commas missing... Just now happened to me.

Answer (score 13):

I'm pretty sure its because angular tries to evaluate the bits in the quotes. Try adding single quotes and see if the message goes away

```
<div data-ip-recent-activity-item 
  title="'My Item Title'" 
  icon="'My item icon'" 
  timeago="'4 hours ago'" 
  meta="'someone commented on an issue in garageband'">
  My Item content
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, turns out angular aggressively caches the directive templates and wouldn't let go of an out of date version that threw those errors, no idea why it would still render properly on the page though.. Tricky stuff  
---
Note: that I've updated the initial question with my solution, since I'm too much of a nub to answer my own question for another 7 hours....

Comment: This helped me when I wanted to put a link in a attribute's directive. thanks !